# Php mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql

Can somebody please tell me what I did wrong in the code below?

Also, I would like to paginate the result.

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "yvens47", "tij43gt") or die("unable to connect to database");
$data = mysql_select_db("phppractice", $link) or die("no such database");

$display = "SELECT * FROM phppractice(Name,Email,Phone)";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($display)) {
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

Comment: What’s the error? And what does pagination have to do with this? Also, one of the things you did wrong is `mysql_`; it’s deprecated in PHP 5.5. Try PDO or MySQLi instead.

Comment: Don't use **mysql_***. Deprecated.

Comment: And that’s not even correct SQL.

Comment: Can you first tell us what you think you did wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to run your incorrect query

```
$sql = "SELECT Name,Email,Phone FROM phppractice";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The query itself is not valid.  Perhaps:

```
SELECT `Name`, `Email`, `Phone` from phppractice;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, for one, your syntax of $display is wrong. Second, you never execute the statement either.

Answer (score 1):

This query is meaningless:

```
SELECT * FROM phppractice(Name,Email,Phone)
```

Are you trying to just select fileds named Name, Email, and Phone?  If so, use this

```
SELECT Name, Email, Phone FROM phppractice
```

On top of this, you never actual call `mysql_query()`. So the qieru never gets executed.

Also, do not use `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated (notice the big red warning on the PHP manual documentation?).  I would suggest `mysqli_*` functions as an easy alternative.

Also, you should always provide error handling to your database queries.  If you simply would have logged or echo the MySQL error, and actually made a query attempt, you would have known right away that you had invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

**WRONG**

```
SELECT * FROM phppractice(Name,Email,Phone)
```

It should be

```
SELECT Name,Email,Phone FROM phppractice
```